# Separate a string with a certain pattern into a dictionary

Tags: c#, string, design-patterns

The user enter this:

```
{YYYY}./.{mm}-{CNo}\/{WEPNo}#{XNo+YNo}
```

How would you read and separate such a string into a dictionary like this:

```
new Dictionary<String, String>() {
  {"YYYY", "./." },
  {"mm", "-"},
  {"CNo", @"\/"},
  {"WEPNo", "#"},
  {"XNo+YNo", ""}
};
```

Comment: What is the key and what is the value in the expected result? It is not clear from your example.

Comment: The key are the brackets {} and its content like 'YYYY'. The value is always after the bracket '}'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combing regular expressions and LINQ you can do it like this:

```
var input = @"{YYYY}./.{mm}-{CNo}\/{WEPNo}#{XNo+YNo}";
Regex ex = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>.+?)\}(?<value>[^{}]*)");
var dictionary = ex.Matches(input).Cast<Match>()
  .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["key"].Value, m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Comment: How would you read the key into the dictionary WITH the brackets ?

Answer (score 1):

by using regular expressions:

```
var input = @"{YYYY}./.{mm}-{CNo}\/{WEPNo}#{XNo+YNo}";

Dictionary<string, string> dictonary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Regex ex = new Regex(@"\{(?<key>.+?)\}(?<value>[^{]*)");

foreach (Match match in ex.Matches(input))
{
    dictonary.Add(match.Groups["key"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = @"{YYYY}./.{mm}-{CNo}\/{WEPNo}#{XNo+YNo}";

var dict = str.Split(new String[] { "{" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => String.Concat("{", s))
    .Select(s => new
    {
        key = String.Concat(s.Split(new String[] { "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0], "}"),
        value = s.Split(new String[] { "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1],
    })
    .ToDictionary(s => s.key, s => s.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use regular expressions to parse the input string.
Then, I would create a class that had all of the values, and override the `.ToString()` method to output back to its original string value.

Also, you should probably show at least one "Example" value of the input string. Otherwise, it's somewhat difficult to interpret your question and provide a solid, code-based answer.